# Jersey Jetty Embedded Won't Read Path Annotation, Error 404

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

Please help me guys I'm going insane here..

So I was trying to use jersey (2.22.1) in an embedded jetty (9.2.14.v20151106), with the very simple main app like this:

```
public class MainApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
            sh.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "etc.mypackage");
            sh.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_SCANNING_RECURSIVE, "true");
            sh.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
            sh.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.tracing", "ALL");
            sh.setInitOrder(1);
            sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
        context.addServlet(sh, "/");
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

One of the thing that is not working here is that the jersey tracing doesn't seem to be working even if I set it in the parameter.

And I have 2 servlets at *`etc.mypackage.servlets`* :

```
@Path("/")
public class TestServlet {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testString){ return "TestServlet.class; }

    @Path("test1")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getString(){
        String test = "TestServlet.class second method called";
        return test;
    }
}
```

and the other with identical functions but with different path and debug string :

```
@Path("/2")
public class TestServlet2 {
    @Path("/test1")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testString){ return "TestServlet2.class; }

    @Path("test2")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getString(){
        String test = "TestServlet2.class second method called";
        return test;
    }
}
```

These codes run and if called it in **http://localhost:8080/** it will return a plain text **TestClass.class** from the first method of that class, but if I added any more path in the link, it will just return the same string, and no way I could invoke for it to display the second method of **TestServlet** class or **TestServlet2**.

But if changed the path from **TestServlet** from **@Path("/")** into anything other than that, it will just return error 404 for any URL including the  **http://localhost:8080/**. I tried everything that I can think of the causes to but no avail, and it's so frustrating. Am I missing something here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `context.addServlet(sh, "/");` you are telling what path to match for access to the servlet. So the only access point you have is `/`. if you want access to *"anything after `/`"*, you should add the wildcard `*`. So just change it to `.addServlet(sh, "/*");`

Comment: It works !! I can't believe that that really was the problem, because I was pretty sure I had tried with the wildcard, but I must've changed something before. Thank you very very much